# cuda dll files not found

Tags: dll, cuda

I am using zed camera for 3D mapping(https://www.stereolabs.com/). The camera comes with a software devolopment kit. The development kit makes use of Nvidia graphics card and CUDA7.5 toolkit. The SDK setup automatically checks for CUDA on pc and installs it if not  present.

The problem I am facing is that when I run the software it gives an error messages that it cannot find nppi64_75.dll, cudart64_75.dll, nppc64_75.dll. However, CUDA 7.5 is already installed and I can see these dll files in "NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit" folder in the same drive. But why the software cannot find these files? And what should I do? I am using windows 10, 64 bit. I have tried reinstalling the software and CUDA toolkit but it doesn't work and it works easily on other computers.

Note: I would like to mention that earlier I had some problem with the camera drivers and camera wasn't working but the software was able to locate the CUDA dll files. I uninstalled everything including CUDA toolkit and reinstalled and now i am stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, cuda 7.5 is already installed and i can see these dll files in "NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit" folder in the same drive. But why the software cannot find these files?

The DLLs are not found, because the CUDA Computing Toolkit installation folder is not a standard search path. Either add it to the system's `PATH` environment variable, or copy the DLLs into the same folder in which your `.exe` resides. You can also implement a wrapper `.bat` file that sets path accordingly (just for that invocation) and then launches the program.